# Japanese text in TextField with embedded font

Tags: actionscript-3

In my ActionScript 3 project I use TextField with embedded font set to true and isHTML set to true. Everything works fine when I display latin characters.

But when I want to display Japanese characters they do not appear. Actually it is expected to be like this because Japanese font is not embedded.

Is there is a way to fall back to system font if embedded font doesn't have glyphs for certain characters?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `hasGlyphs("...");` on a `Font` instance. I had some problems with it but in general it works alright, hopefully it works for Japanese too. Then you can simply use _sans if there is no japanese glyphs.

Edit:
I have no way to test this now but I assume something like this would work:

```
import flash.text.Font;

var myFont:Font = new MyFont(); // Embedded font in library, linkage set to 'MyFont'

if(myFont.hasGlyphs("Hello!")) {
    field.embedFonts = true; // Not sure whether this is necessary in case of HTML text
    field.htmlText = "<p><font color='#ff0000' face='" + myFont.fontName + "'>Hello!</font></p>";   
}
else {
    field.embedFonts = false;
    field.htmlText = "<p><font color='#ff0000' face='_sans'>Hello!</font></p>";
}
```

Comment: I just tried `face='_sans'` but it doesn't show characters. Could you please provide more details?

Comment: +Fygo yeah, I see you embeddedFonts = false. I al looking for the way to show both embedded and not embedded fonts at the same time somehow... I think it is impossible.

Comment: Try removing embed fonts and then DO test it on a machine that the font is not installed on. (I have no idea how it works exactly with html text) Then just put *field.htmlText = "<p><font color='#ff0000' face='" + myFont.fontName + "'>Hello!</font><font color='#ff0000' face='_sans'>Hello!</font></p>";*

Comment: Hi Fygo, thank you for your time. I think it is just impossible to use embedded and not embedded fonts at the same time. Moreover I run my app on iPad. I think it adds extra limitations.

Comment: Embed them both then, the Latin chars are never a big problem anyway, there is few of them. :) Well, tried to help, good luck!